# Group values in to categories with annual break down

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have a table of licence applications **I want to display the data by category for each financial year**.

For my query, there are 2 key columns.

Firstly, there is a `fee` column and the values within this column determine the type of licence.

- Between 0 and 300 is Minor
- between 300 and 600 is Standard
- between 600 and 2000 is Major

Secondly, there is a `date` field which is to be used for the financial year.

I would like the results to look like this.

```
Category | 2013/14 | 2012/13
Minor    |      23 |      21
Standard |      10 |      11 
Major    |       5 |       3
```

I have this query below, but i cant get it right for the year part.
Would really appreciate any advice people can give me.

```
select category.gr as [category],
sum(case when ((year(licence.[start_date]) in ('2010')) 
and (month(licence.[start_date]) in (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)))
or ((year(licence.[start_date]) in ('2011')) 
and (month(licence.[start_date]) in (1,2,3))) then 1 else 0 end) AS '10/11 Count',

from (  select case
when [fee_INC] between 0 and 350 then 'Minor'
when [fee_INC] between 350 and 600 then 'Standard'
else 'Major' end as gr
from [L_LICENCE_FIN]) as category,
from [L_LICENCE_FIN] as licence

group by category.gr
```

Comment: What is the definition of *Financial Year*?

Comment: Our financial year is April - March.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  [category],
  [2013/14],
  [2012/13]
FROM (
  SELECT
    [category],
    STR(YEAR(DATEADD(month,-3,[start_date])),4)
      +'/'
      +RIGHT(STR(YEAR(DATEADD(month,-3,[start_date]))+1,4),2)
      AS [fiscal_year],
    COUNT(*) AS [count]
  FROM @L_LICENCE_FIN
  INNER JOIN (VALUES
    (  0, 300, 'Minor'),
    (300, 600, 'Standard'),
    (600,2000, 'Major')
  ) categories([fee_min], [fee_max], [category])
    ON ([fee] >= [fee_min] AND [fee] < [fee_max])
  GROUP BY [category],[start_date]
) p1
PIVOT(SUM([count]) FOR [fiscal_year] IN ([2013/14],[2012/13])) p2
```

Comment: Thank you for this.
I understand most of it, but I am getting a syntax error on 'VALUES' on line 14.
Also, I cant see where we are stating the actual field name.
In the table the field is 'FEE_INC'